# How to list order items with order total per item

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `booking` and `order_items` where `booking` has many `order_items`. I need to create a query where I list all order_items group by booking id but in each item line I need to show the total of the booking (for instance, booking id 1 has 2 order_items costing £10 each so I need the query to show:)

```
item 1 name price (£10) discount booking total (in this case £20)
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    b.partner_order_id,
    'Store Name' as 'Store',
    CONCAT_WS(' ', b.customer_firstname, b.customer_lastname) AS 'Name',
    '1' as 'Quantity',
    oi.order_price as 'Price',
    oi.discount as 'Discount',
    SUM(order_price - discount) as 'Payment',
    '0' as 'Shipping',
    'Sale' as 'Transaction',
    oi.order_sku as 'SKU',
    oi.order_name as 'Description',
    oi.order_color as 'Colour',
    oi.order_size as 'Size'
FROM booking AS b
     JOIN order_items oi on b.booking_id = oi.booking_id
WHERE
    b.delivery_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 8 DAY and
    b.partner_id = 36 and
    oi.item_accepted = 1
GROUP BY oi.id
```

Which does almost everything I need apart from giving me the total per booking on each item line. Any ideas?

Comment: `group by b.booking_id` ?

Comment: if I do `group by b.booking_id` it does group and it gives me the total for the booking, but doesn't show individual items. I need the individual items with the total in each line

Comment: Group by is tiered left to right in the group by terms.

Comment: Sorry @P.Salmon but I'm not sure I follow...

Comment: Group by o.id, order_items and clarify your question by including sample data and expected output as text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a sub query to your select like this:

```
SELECT
    b.partner_order_id,
    'Store Name' as 'Store',
    CONCAT_WS(' ', b.customer_firstname, b.customer_lastname) AS 'Name',
    '1' as 'Quantity',
    oi.order_price as 'Price',
    oi.discount as 'Discount',
    SUM(order_price - discount) as 'Payment',
    '0' as 'Shipping',
    'Sale' as 'Transaction',
    oi.order_sku as 'SKU',
    oi.order_name as 'Description',
    oi.order_color as 'Colour',
    oi.order_size as 'Size',
    (SELECT SUM(order_price) FROM order_items WHERE booking_id = b.booking_id) AS total
FROM booking AS b
     JOIN order_items oi on b.booking_id = oi.booking_id
WHERE
    b.delivery_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 8 DAY and
    b.partner_id = 36 and
    oi.item_accepted = 1
GROUP BY oi.id
```